SharedTransitionLayout cauding crash with constrain layout
I am using sharedTransitionLayout in my app, and composables in my NavHost were previously not using ConstraintLayout, I recently used ConstraintLayout in few composables in my navigation screens and I started seeing this crash, can anyone help here
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error: Placement happened before lookahead.
    at androidx.compose.ui.internal.InlineClassHelperKt.throwIllegalStateException(InlineClassHelper.kt:26)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeSelf-MLgxB_4(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:2110)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:765)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:621)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:259)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.compose.Measurer.performLayout(ConstraintLayout.kt:1321)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayoutKt$rememberConstraintLayoutMeasurePolicy$1$measurePolicy$1$measure$1.invoke(ConstraintLayout.kt:123)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayoutKt$rememberConstraintLayoutMeasurePolicy$1$measurePolicy$1$measure$1.invoke(ConstraintLayout.kt:122)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildrenBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:429)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildrenBlock$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:424)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:503)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:502)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:258)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:83)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:457)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:627)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.onAfterPlaceAt(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:182)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:169)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:621)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:1019)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WrapContentNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:1011)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.onAfterPlaceAt(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:270)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:247)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:609)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:232)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:704)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode$measure$1.invoke(Size.kt:703)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LookaheadCapablePlaceable$layout$1.placeChildren(LookaheadDelegate.kt:223)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.onAfterPlaceAt(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:270)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:247)

This my nav host structure:
SharedTransitionLayout{
        NavHost(
            modifier = modifier.background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.htl_background)),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = SelectRoomDestination.SELECT_ROOM_SCREEN.name
        ) {
            
            composable(
                "plan",
            ) {
                // screen using constraint layout
            }
            
            composable(
                "listing"
            ) {
                // screen using constraint layout
            }
            composable("detail") {
                // screen using constraint layout
            }
        }
    }

